# List GetRange error in C#

Tags: c#

i am working with list and my list has 14 record.

```
 List<Product> oProduct = new List<Product> 
        {
           new Product("../images/1.jpg", "Sample Data.1"),
           new Product("../images/2.jpg", "Sample Data.2"),
           new Product("../images/3.jpg", "Sample Data.3"),
           new Product("../images/4.jpg", "Sample Data.4"),
           new Product("../images/5.jpg", "Sample Data.5"),
           new Product("../images/6.jpg", "Sample Data.6"),
           new Product("../images/7.jpg", "Sample Data.7"),
           new Product("../images/8.jpg", "Sample Data.8"),
           new Product("../images/9.jpg", "Sample Data.9"),
           new Product("../images/10.jpg", "Sample Data.10"),
           new Product("../images/11.jpg", "Sample Data.11"),
           new Product("../images/12.jpg", "Sample Data.12"),
           new Product("../images/13.jpg", "Sample Data.13"),
           new Product("../images/14.jpg", "Sample Data.14"),
        };
```

when i use the below line for getrange then i am getting index out of bound error.

```
List<Product> xProduct = oProduct.GetRange(10, 13);
```

but my list has 14 element then why i can not extract data from 10th position to 14th position....please guide thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The second parameter to [`GetRange`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/21k0e39c.aspx) needs to be the **count** of elements to get, so change it to `4` (I think that's what you want).

Also, the first parameter is the **zero**-based index, so you want `GetRange(9, 4)` to get images 10 through 13.

Comment: And don't forget that the **count** must be a valid number of elements. It's annoying to get an `ArgumentException` thrown when the tail end of the list is shorter than **count**.

Answer (score 3):

`List<T>.GetRange` takes `start` and `count`, not `start` and `end`. If you want elements 10-13, use `GetRange(10, 4)`.

Answer (score 1):

You are asking for 13 elements, starting from element ten.